# Ruby hash: return the first key value under which is not nil

Tags: ruby

Say I have a hash

```
hash = {a:1, b:false, c:nil}
```

& a series of keys somewhere: `[:c, :b, :a]`. Is there a Ruby idiom for returning such a key value under which != nil?

The obv

```
[:c, :b, :a].select {|key| hash[key] != nil}.first     # returns :b
```

seems too long.

Comment: I got ":a" from your code. // sorry I now see that you are asking for more short expression.

Comment: @set0gut1 exactly

Comment: do you want it to return the key/value or just the value(s)?

Comment: @Anthony only the _key_

Comment: What if `hash = {a:1, b:1, c:nil}` and `[:c, :b, :a]`?

Comment: @iGian should return `:b`

Comment: Your block variable should be named `key`. Also this will give exclude not only `nil` but `false` values from the selection as well.

Comment: @SagarPandya hahaha, yeah! I see the confusion now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For that I think [`Enumerable#find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) might work:

```
find(ifnone = nil) { |obj| block } → obj or nil
find(ifnone = nil) → an_enumerator
```

> Passes each entry in enum to block. Returns the first for which block
>   is not false. If no object matches, calls `ifnone` and returns its
>   result when it is specified, or returns `nil` otherwise.
>
> If no block is given, an enumerator is returned instead.

In your case it'd return the first for which block is not `nil`:

```
p %i[c b a].find { |key| !{ a: 1, b: nil, c: nil }[key].nil? } # :a
p %i[c b a].find { |key| !{ a: 1, b: 1, c: nil }[key].nil? }   # :b
```

Comment: Still wrong. `is not nil` is not the same as `is truthy`

Comment: @Ilya 5y later, but it should probably be mentioned that the answer was fixed to better reflect the question :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to filter elements with falsy values, you can use the following expressions.

```
keys = [:d, :c, :b, :a]
hash = { a: 1, b: nil, c: nil, d: 2 }
keys.select(&hash)
#  => [:d, :a]
```

If you want to filter elements with exactly nil as a value, it is not correct, as Mr. Ilya wrote.

Comment: `{a: 1, b: nil, c: false, d: 2 }` => `[:d, :a]`

Comment: up, very smart! `keys.select(&hash).first`

Comment: `keys.find(&hash)` is shorter if you want the first element that meets the condition.

Comment: Please note that `Hash#to_proc` is only available in Ruby 2.3.0 or better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `detect` this will return first value if match.
`[:c, :b, :a].detect { |key| hash[key] != nill }`. This will return :b.
Hope to help you :D